# How can I build a simple menu in Perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, oop, menu, submenu

I'm working on a Perl script that requires some basic menu functionality. Ultimately I would like each menu to have a few options and then the option to either return to the previous menu or exit.

example:

This is a menu:

1. Choice 1
2. Choice 2
3. Return to previous menu
4. Exit

Select an option:

I currently have a menu subroutine making the menus, but there is no functionality allowing it to go back to the previous menu.

```
    sub menu
    {
        for (;;) {
            print "--------------------\n";
            print "$_[0]\n";
            print "--------------------\n";
            for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@{ $_[1]}); $i++) {
                print $i + 1, "\.\t ${ $_[1] }[$i]\n";
            }
            print "\n?: ";
            my $i = <STDIN>; chomp $i;
            if ($i && $i =~ m/[0-9]+/ && $i <= scalar(@{ $_[1]})) {
                return ${ $_[1] }[$i - 1];
            } else {
                print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    # Using the menu
    my $choice1  = menu('Menu1 header', \@list_of_choices1);

    # I would like this menu to give the option to go back to
    # the first menu to change $choice1
    my $choice2 = menu('Menu2 header', \@list_of_choices2);
```

I don't want to hard code all of the menus and use if/elsif statements for all of the processing so I turned the menu into a function.

My menus currently look like this...

Menu Header:

1. Choice1
2. Choice2
3. Choice3

?: (Enter input here)

This solution still doesn't allow the user to go back to the previous menu or exit though. I was considering making a menu class to handle the menus, but I am still not very good with object oriented Perl.  This is a small program with only a few menus so using a complex menu building module may be overkill.  I would like to keep my code as light as possible.

## EDIT:

Thanks for the quick responses! However there is still an issue. When I select an option from "Menu1" and it progresses to "Menu2" I would like the save the choice from "Menu1" for later use:

Menu1:

1. Choice1 <-- store value if selected and go to next menu
2. Choice2 <-- ...
3. Exit    <-- quit

Menu2:

1. Choice1 <-- store value if selected and go to next menu
2. Choice2 <-- ...
3. Back    <-- go back to previous menu to reselect value
4. Exit    <-- quit

Selecting either Choice1 or Choice2 should store a value in a variable for later use ***and*** progress to the next menu.  Then if you choose to go back to the first menu from Menu2, it will give you the option to reselect your choice and redefine the variable.  I'm trying to avoid using global variables which makes this quite difficult.

After progressing through all of the menus and setting the values of all of these variables, I want to run a subroutine to process all of the choices and print a final output.

```
 sub main () {

   # DO MENU STUFF HERE

   # PROCESS RESULTS FROM MENU CHOICES
   my $output = process($menu1_choice, $menu2_choice, $menu3_choice, ... );
 }
```

Also if anyone has an object oriented approach to this using classes or some other data structure, although it may be overkill, I would still love to see it and try to wrap my head around the idea!

Comment: Wondering if this would help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/ncurses-based-menus

Comment: [Term::Choose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Choose) provides the option `default` which sets the menu element selected by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few more months of programming with Perl I learned much more about how to deal with objects and wrote a simple object oriented menu building module based off of friedo's answer.

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $class = shift;
    my (%args) = @_;
    my $title       = $args{title};
    my $choices_ref = $args{choices};
    my $noexit      = $args{noexit};

    # Bless the menu object
    my $self = bless {
        title   => $title,
        choices => $choices_ref,
        noexit  => $noexit,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $self = shift;
    my $title   =   $self->{title  };
    my @choices = @{$self->{choices}};
    my $noexit  =   $self->{noexit };

    # Print menu
    for (;;) {

        # Clear the screen
        system 'cls';

        # Print menu title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $title\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu options
        my $counter = 0;
        for my $choice(@choices) {
            printf "%2d. %s\n", ++$counter, $choice->{text};
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", '0', 'Exit' unless $noexit;

        print "\n?: ";

        # Get user input
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        print "\n";

        # Process input
        if ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input >= 1 && $input <= $counter) {
            return $choices[$input - 1]{code}->();
        } elsif ($input =~ m/\d+/ && !$input && !$noexit) {
            print "Exiting . . .\n";
            exit 0;
        } else {
            print "Invalid input.\n\n";
            system 'pause';
        }
    }
}

1;
```

Using this module you can build menus and link them together relatively easy.  See example of usage below:

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Menu;

my $menu1;
my $menu2;

# define menu1 choices
my @menu1_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu2',
      code => sub { $menu2->print(); }},
);

# define menu2 choices
my @menu2_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu1',
      code => sub { $menu1->print(); }},
);

# Build menu1
$menu1 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu1',
    choices => \@menu1_choices,
);

# Build menu2
$menu2 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu2',
    choices => \@menu2_choices,
    noexit  => 1,
);

# Print menu1
$menu1->print();
```

This code will create a simple menu with a submenu.  Once in the submenu you can easily go back to the previous menu.

Thanks for all of the great answers! They really helped me figure this out and I don't think i would have ended up with such a good solution without all the help!

---

**A BETTER SOLUTION:**

*Say goodbye to those ugly arrays of hashes!*

Some of the code internal to the Menu.pm and Item.pm modules may look slightly confusing, but this new design makes the interface of building the menus themselves much cleaner and more efficient.

After some careful code reworking and making the individual menu items into their own objects I was able to create a much cleaner interface for creating menus.  Here is my new code:

This is a test script showing an example of how to use the modules to build menus.

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Menu;

# Create a menu object
my $menu = Menu->new();

# Add a menu item
$menu->add(
    'Test'  => sub { print "This is a test\n";  system 'pause'; },
    'Test2' => sub { print "This is a test2\n"; system 'pause'; },
    'Test3' => sub { print "This is a test3\n"; system 'pause'; },
);

# Allow the user to exit directly from the menu
$menu->exit(1);

# Disable a menu item
$menu->disable('Test2');
$menu->print();

# Do not allow the user to exit directly from the menu
$menu->exit(0);

# Enable a menu item
$menu->enable('Test2');
$menu->print();
```

The Menu.pm module is used to build menu objects.  These menu objects can contain multiple Menu::Item objects.  The objects are stored in an array so their order is preserved.

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Carp;
use Menu::Item;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $title) = @_;

    # Define a default title
    if (!defined $title) {
        $title = 'MENU';
    }

    # Bless the Menu object
    my $self = bless {
        _title => $title,
        _items => [],
        _exit  => 0,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Title accessor method
sub title {
    my ($self, $title) = @_;
    $self->{_title} = $title if defined $title;
    return $self->{_title};
}

# Items accessor method
sub items {
    my ($self, $items) = @_;
    $self->{_items} = $items if defined $items;
    return $self->{_items};
}

# Exit accessor method
sub exit {
    my ($self, $exit) = @_;
    $self->{_exit} = $exit if defined $exit;
    return $self->{_exit};
}

# Add item(s) to the menu
sub add {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @add) = @_;
    croak 'add() requires name-action pairs' unless @add % 2 == 0;

    # Add new items
    while (@add) {
        my ($name, $action) = splice @add, 0, 2;

        # If the item already exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }

        # Add the item to the end of the menu
        my $item = Menu::Item->new($name, $action);
        push @{$self->{_items}}, $item;
    }

    return 0;
}

# Remove item(s) from the menu
sub remove {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @remove) = @_;

    # Remove items
    for my $name(@remove) {

        # If the item exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Disable item(s)
sub disable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @disable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@disable) {

        # If the item exists, disable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Enable item(s)
sub enable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @enable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@enable) {

        # If the item exists, enable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self) = @_;

    # Print the menu
    for (;;) {
        system 'cls';

        # Print the title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $self->{_title}\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu items
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $name   = $self->{_items}->[$index]->name();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$index]->active();
            if ($active) {
                printf "%2d. %s\n", $index + 1, $name;
            } else {
                print "\n";
            }
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", 0, 'Exit' if $self->{_exit};

        # Get user input
        print "\n?: ";
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        # Process user input
        if ($input =~ m/^\d+$/ && $input > 0 && $input <= scalar @{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $action = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->action();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->active();
            if ($active) {
                print "\n";
                return $action->();
            }
        } elsif ($input =~ m/^\d+$/ && $input == 0 && $self->{_exit}) {
            exit 0;
        }

        # Deal with invalid input
        print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
        system 'pause';
    }
}

1;
```

The Item.pm Module must be stored in a subfolder called "Menu" In order for it to be referenced properly.  This module lets you create Menu::Item objects that contain a name and a subroutine reference.  These objects will be what the user selects from in the menu.

```
# Item.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu::Item;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu::Item constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $name, $action) = @_;

    # Bless the Menu::Item object
    my $self = bless {
        _name   => $name,
        _action => $action,
        _active => 1,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Name accessor method
sub name {
    my ($self, $name) = @_;
    $self->{_name} = $name if defined $name;
    return $self->{_name};
}

# Action accessor method
sub action {
    my ($self, $action) = @_;
    $self->{_action} = $action if defined $action;
    return $self->{_action};
}

# Active accessor method
sub active {
    my ($self, $active) = @_;
    $self->{_active} = $active if defined $active;
    return $self->{_active};
}

1;
```

This design is a vast improvement over my previous design and makes creating menus much easier and cleaner.

Let me know what you think.

Any comments, thoughts, or improvement ideas?

Comment: I'm working on an even better solution :) I'll edit this post when it's done!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a module such as [Term::Choose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Choose/lib/Term/Choose.pm):

```
use Term::Choose qw( choose );

my $submenus = {
    menu1 => [ qw( s_1 s_2 s_3 ) ],
    menu2 => [ qw( s_4 s_5 s_6 s_7) ],
    menu3 => [ qw( s_8 s_9 ) ],
};
my @menus = ( qw( menu1 menu2 menu3 ) );
my $mm = 0;
MAIN: while ( 1 ) {
    my $i = choose( 
        [ undef, @menus ],
        { layout => 3, undef => 'quit', index => 1, default => $mm }
    );
    last if ! $i;
    if ( $mm == $i ) {
        $mm = 0;
        next MAIN;
    }
    else {
        $mm = $i;
    }
    $i--;
    SUB: while ( 1 ) {
        my $choice = choose(
            [ undef, @{$submenus->{$menus[$i]}} ],
            { layout => 3, undef => 'back' }
        );
        last SUB if ! defined $choice;
        say "choice: $choice";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go full OO with this, a simple way that you can make this a lot more flexible is to allow each menu choice to control how it is executed. Let's say each menu has an array of hashes that contain the menu text and a coderef that implements what the menu does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub menu {
    my @items = @_;

    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $item( @items ) {
        printf "%d: %s\n", ++$count, $item->{text};
    }

    print "\n?: ";

    while( my $line = <STDIN> ) {
        chomp $line;
        if ( $line =~ m/\d+/ && $line <= @items ) {
            return $items[ $line - 1 ]{code}->();
        }

        print "\nInvalid input\n\n?: ";
    }
}

my @menu_choices;
my @other_menu_choices;

@menu_choices = (
    { text  => 'do something',
      code  => sub { print "I did something!\n" } },
    { text  => 'do something else',
      code  => sub { print "foobar!\n" } },
    { text  => 'go to other menu',
      code  => sub { menu( @other_menu_choices ) } }
);

@other_menu_choices = (
    { text  => 'go back',
      code  => sub { menu( @menu_choices ) } }
);

menu( @menu_choices );
```

The `menu` subroutine takes an array of options, and each option "knows" how to perform its own action. If you want to switch between menus, the menu option just calls `menu` again with a different list of options, as in the "go back" example from `@other_menu_choices`. This make linking between menus very easy and it's also easy to add exit options and such.

To keep this code clean and readable, for anything other than trivial menu actions, use a named reference to a subroutine instead of an anonymous subroutine reference. For example:

```
@another_menu_options = (
    { text => 'complicated action'
      code => \&do_complicated_action
    }
);

sub do_complicated_action { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does this line work `return $items[ $line - 1 ]{code}->();`? Why doesn't it work if you type it this way `return $items[ $line - 1 ]->{code};`?  I guess I don't fully understand how anonymous subroutines in hashes work.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, the `->` operator is for dereferencing, but in a compound structure it may be omitted between levels. So `$ref->[0]->{foo}->[2]` is the same as `$ref->[0]{foo}[2]`. But for sub refs, you have to use the `->` to invoke the sub, otherwise Perl thinks you want to return the sub reference itself. So you could also write `return $items[ $line - 1 ]->{code}->();`. The `->()` is needed to invoke the sub instead of just returning it as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one approach. Each choice has an associated subroutine. When the choice is made, the corresponding subroutine is called. Here I am using anonymous subroutines but you can also use references to named subroutines.

```
use warnings; use strict;

sub menu {
  my $args = shift;
  my $title = $args->{title};
  my $choices = $args->{choices};

  while (1) {
    print "--------------------\n";
    print "$title\n";
    print "--------------------\n";
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= scalar(@$choices); $i++) {
      my $itemHeading = $choices->[$i-1][0];
      print "$i.\t $itemHeading\n";
    }
    print "\n?: ";
    my $i = <STDIN>; chomp $i;
    if ($i && $i =~ m/[0-9]+/ && $i <= scalar(@$choices)) {
      &{$choices->[$i-1][1]}();
    } else {
      print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
    }
  }
}

my $menus = {};
$menus = {
  "1" => {
    "title" => "Menu 1 header",
    "choices" => [
       [ "Choice 1" , sub { print "Choice 1 selected"; }],
       [ "Choice 2" , sub { print "Choice 2 selected"; }],
       [ "Menu 2" , sub { menu($menus->{2}); }],
       [ "Exit" , sub { exit; }],
    ],
  },
 "2" => {
    "title" => "Menu 2 header",
    "choices" => [
       [ "Choice 3" , sub { print "Choice 3 selected"; }],
       [ "Choice 4" , sub { print "Choice 4 selected"; }],
       [ "Menu 1" , sub { menu($menus->{1}); }],
       [ "Exit" , sub { exit; }],
  ],
  },
};

menu($menus->{1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the responses! All three of the responses were helpful in finally coming up with my solution.  I decided to go with the Term::Choose module, (Thanks sid_com for the idea).  My menu structure was different than you had originally suggested and it took quite a while of scratching my head to figure out how to make it do exactly what I wanted.  Hopefully this solution will help someone else out who encounters a similar problem.

I constructed the menu as shown below:

(*I have replaced my variables with more general names so it is easier to follow*)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Term::Choose qw(choose);

    my @CHOICES1 = ('A','B','C');
    my @CHOICES2 = ('1','2','3');
    my @CHOICES3 = ('BLUE','YELLOW','GREEN');

    # function to use the choices
    sub some_function {
        print "THIS IS SOME FUNCTION!\n";
        print "Choice 1 is $_[0]\n";
        print "Choice 2 is $_[1]\n";
        print "Choice 3 is $_[2]\n";
        print "Have a nice day! :)\n";
    }

    sub main() {

        # clear the screen
        # (for some reason the build in screen clear 
        # for the module was not working for me)
        system ('cls');

        # create menu object
        my $menu = new Term::Choose();

        # menu 1
        for (;;) {
            my $choice1 = $menu->choose(
                [@CHOICES1, undef],
                {
                    prompt => 'Select a choice1:',
                    undef  => 'Exit',
                    layout => 3,
                }
            );
            last if ! $choice1;

            # submenu 1
            for (;;) {
                my $choice2 = $menu->choose(
                    [@CHOICES2, undef],
                    {
                        prompt => 'Select a choice2:',
                        undef  => 'Back',
                        layout => 3,
                    }
                );
                last if ! $choice2;

                # submenu2
                for (;;) {
                    my $choice3 = $menu->choose(
                        [@CHOICES3, undef],
                        {
                             prompt => 'Select a choice3:',
                            undef  => 'Back',
                            layout => 3,
                        }
                    );
                    last if ! $choice3;

                    # function operating on all choices
                    some_function($choice1, $choice2, $choice3);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    main();
```

I'm still very new to object oriented Perl so this took a very long time to figure out and it might not be perfect, but it gets the job done.  Let me know if you have any ideas or improvements!

Answer (score -1):

I have found this old module without any perldoc in my perl modules...
Please, give it a try...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    BEGIN { $Curses::OldCurses = 1; }
    use Curses;
    use perlmenu;
    &menu_init(0,"Select an Animal"); # Init menu

    &menu_item("Collie","dog"); # Add item
    &menu_item("Shetland","pony"); # Add item
    &menu_item("Persian","cat"); # Add last item

    $sel = &menu_display("Which animal?"); # Get user selection

    if ($sel eq "dog") {print "Its Lassie!\n";}
```