# Conditionally Excluding Menu Choices From a Menu

Tags: perl, user-interface, menu, conditional-statements, submenu

I wrote a Perl module that can build simple menus and manage them, but now I need to figure out how to conditionally hide menu choices when I don't want them to be available.

For example how could I make it hide `"Choice2"` in `$menu1` if a specific condition is met?

This question is somewhat of a continuation off of one of my other questions:
[How can I build a simple menu in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438475/how-can-i-build-a-simple-menu-in-perl)

I've made quite a bit of progress since I've started this, but I seem to have hit a roadblock.

The Menu module looks like this:

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $class       = shift;
    my (%args)      = @_;
    my $title       = $args{title};
    my $choices_ref = $args{choices};
    my $noexit      = $args{noexit};

    # Bless the menu object
    my $self = bless {
        title   => $title,
        choices => $choices_ref,
        noexit  => $noexit,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $self    = shift;
    my $title   =   $self->{title  };
    my @choices = @{$self->{choices}};
    my $noexit  =   $self->{noexit };

    # Print menu
    for (;;) {

        # Clear the screen
        system 'cls';

        # Print menu title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $title\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu options
        my $index = 0;
        for my $choice(@choices) {
            printf "%2d. %s\n", ++$index, $choice->{text};
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", '0', 'Exit' unless $noexit;

        print "\n?: ";

        # Get user input
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        print "\n";

        # Process input
        if ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input >= 1 && $input <= $index) {
            return $choices[$input - 1]{code}->();
        } elsif ($input =~ m/\d+/ && !$input && !$noexit) {
            print "Exiting . . .\n";
            exit 0;
        } else {
            print "Invalid input.\n\n";
            system 'pause';
        }
    }
}

1;
```

Here is an example of how the module is used:

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Menu;

my $menu1;
my $menu2;

# define menu1 choices
my @menu1_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu2',
      code => sub { $menu2->print(); }},
);

# define menu2 choices
my @menu2_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu1',
      code => sub { $menu1->print(); }},
);

# Build menu1
$menu1 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu1',
    choices => \@menu1_choices,
);

# Build menu2
$menu2 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu2',
    choices => \@menu2_choices,
);

# Print menu1
$menu1->print();
```

Since the menus choices are defined as an array of hashes, I'm not sure how I can conditionally exclude specific options if I don't want them to be shown.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks lovedatsnow for the idea to make the items their own object!  I basically took your answer and revamped it to make the interface for creating a menu look much cleaner than it did before.

Here is my new code:

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Menu;

# Create a menu object
my $menu = Menu->new();

# Add a menu item
$menu->add(
    'Test'  => sub { print "This is a test\n";  system 'pause'; },
    'Test2' => sub { print "This is a test2\n"; system 'pause'; },
    'Test3' => sub { print "This is a test3\n"; system 'pause'; },
);

# Disable a menu item
$menu->disable('Test2');
$menu->print();

# Enable a menu item
$menu->enable('Test2');
$menu->print();
```

I created a menu class with a few useful functions that allow you to act directly on the menu items.  This allows you to enable/disable them easily.

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Carp;
use Menu::Item;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $title) = @_;

    # Define a default title
    if (!defined $title) {
        $title = 'MENU';
    }

    # Bless the Menu object
    my $self = bless {
        _title => $title,
        _items => [],
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Title accessor method
sub title {
    my ($self, $title) = @_;
    $self->{_title} = $title if defined $title;
    return $self->{_title};
}

# Items accessor method
sub items {
    my ($self, $items) = @_;
    $self->{_items} = $items if defined $items;
    return $self->{_items};
}

# Add item(s) to the menu
sub add {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @add) = @_;
    croak 'add() requires name-action pairs' unless @add % 2 == 0;

    # Add new items
    while (@add) {
        my ($name, $action) = splice @add, 0, 2;

        # If the item already exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }

        # Add the item to the end of the menu
        my $item = Menu::Item->new($name, $action);
        push @{$self->{_items}}, $item;
    }

    return 0;
}

# Remove item(s) from the menu
sub remove {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @remove) = @_;

    # Remove items
    for my $name(@remove) {

        # If the item exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Disable item(s)
sub disable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @disable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@disable) {

        # If the item exists, disable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Enable item(s)
sub enable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @enable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@enable) {

        # If the item exists, enable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self) = @_;

    # Print the menu
    for (;;) {
        system 'cls';

        # Print the title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $self->{_title}\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu items
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $name   = $self->{_items}->[$index]->name();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$index]->active();
            if ($active) {
                printf "%2d. %s\n", $index + 1, $name;
            } else {
                print "\n";
            }
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", 0, 'Exit';

        # Get user input
        print "\n?: ";
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        # Process user input
        if ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input > 0 && $input <= scalar @{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $action = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->action();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->active();
            if ($active) {
                print "\n";
                return $action->();
            }
        } elsif ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        # Deal with invalid input
        print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
        system 'pause';
    }
}

1;
```

Lastly I created the Menu::Item class that allows you to create individual items and stores the necessary information for each item. (Note that this is stored in a folder named "Menu" in order for the reference to work properly).

```
# Item.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu::Item;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu::Item constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $name, $action) = @_;

    # Bless the Menu::Item object
    my $self = bless {
        _name   => $name,
        _action => $action,
        _active => 1,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Name accessor method
sub name {
    my ($self, $name) = @_;
    $self->{_name} = $name if defined $name;
    return $self->{_name};
}

# Action accessor method
sub action {
    my ($self, $action) = @_;
    $self->{_action} = $action if defined $action;
    return $self->{_action};
}

# Active accessor method
sub active {
    my ($self, $active) = @_;
    $self->{_active} = $active if defined $active;
    return $self->{_active};
}

1;
```

This creates a very elegant interface for building and using menus!

No more ugly arrays of hashes. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a MenuItem package and then just set a flag in the choice to decide if it should be included or not. Below is a complete code set using the new package when creating the menu choices. To demonstrate it the 'disabled' flag is set for the 2nd choice in the first Menu.

Note there was some additional code added to the 'print' sub routine to deal with disabled choices when calculating the user's response.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MenuItem;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    # Unpack input arguments
    my $class       = shift;
    my (%args)      = @_;
    my $text        = $args{text};
    my $code        = $args{code};
    my $disabled        = $args{disabled};

    # Bless the menu object
    my $self = bless {
        text   => $text,
        code   => $code,
        disabled => $disabled,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

1;

package Menu;

use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $class       = shift;
    my (%args)      = @_;
    my $title       = $args{title};
    my $choices_ref = $args{choices};
    my $noexit      = $args{noexit};

    # Bless the menu object
    my $self = bless {
        title   => $title,
        choices => $choices_ref,
        noexit  => $noexit,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $self    = shift;
    my $title   =   $self->{title  };
    my @choices = @{$self->{choices}};
    my $noexit  =   $self->{noexit };

    # Print menu
    for (;;) {

        # Clear the screen
        system 'cls';

        # Print menu title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $title\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu options
        my $index = 0;
    my @items;
        for my $choice(@choices) {
        if ( ! $choice->{disabled} ) {
        $items[$index]=$choice;
        printf "%2d. %s\n", ++$index, $choice->{text};
        }
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", '0', 'Exit' unless $noexit;

        print "\n?: ";

        # Get user input
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        print "\n";

        # Process input
        if ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input >= 1 && $input <= $index) {
            return $items[$input - 1]->{code}->();
        } elsif ($input =~ m/\d+/ && !$input && !$noexit) {
            print "Exiting . . .\n";
            exit 0;
        } else {
            print "Invalid input.\n\n";
            system 'pause';
        }
    }
}

1;

use strict;
use warnings;

#use Menu;

my $menu1;
my $menu2;

# define menu1 choices
my @menu1_choices = (
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Choice1',
          code => sub { print "I did something!\n"; }),
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Choice2',
          code => sub { print "I did something else!\n"; },
          disabled => 1),
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Go to Menu2',
          code => sub { $menu2->print(); }),
);

# define menu2 choices
my @menu2_choices = (
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Choice1',
          code => sub { print "I did something in menu 2!\n"; }),
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Choice2',
          code => sub { print "I did something else in menu 2!\n"; }),
    MenuItem->new(text => 'Go to Menu1',
          code => sub { $menu1->print(); }),
);

# Build menu1
$menu1 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu1',
    choices => \@menu1_choices,
);

# Build menu2
$menu2 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu2',
    choices => \@menu2_choices,
);

# Print menu1
$menu1->print();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new, here is some constructive feedback. This is a pretty good answer. You tried hard to solve the OPs problem. That's cool and nice and awesome. However, it would be better if you'd just show the relevant piece of code, because right now it is very hard to see what you changed (I only spotted it because you forgot to indent it). It's visually cluttered. Just show an excerpt of the relevant part of code, and put a comment on the stuff you added. Don't do the whole work for other people, but instead help them to solve their own problem so they learn. :)

Comment: Also you forgot `package main;`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are asking. I think you are asking "Given that I have an array of hashes, how can I ignore some of those hashes that contain a particular key?"

You can do that pretty easily with a [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) statement when you create your Menu object:

```
my $menu2 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu2',
    choices => [grep { $_->{text} ne 'Choice2' } @menu2_choices],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is a blacklist as a parameter. Of course you can put that somewhere else, e.g. as an attribute of the object.

Simply check each of those for the blacklist. Or delete them directly from the choice array.

```
sub print {
  my ($self, @blacklist) = @_;
    for my $choice (@choices) {
       printf "%2d. %s\n", ++$index, $choice->{text}
         unless grep { $_ eq $choice->{text} } @blacklist;
    }
}
```